# Changing the title height in a beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, header-footer, scaling

How can I change the height of the title in the `beamer`?

Height of the title block is big and I want to make it smaller and similarly the width of the left block is big and I want to make it smaller too.

I know this is a simple question but I could not find which `.sty` files I need to look.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. That way one can identify the `beamer` template you're using and want to adjust. Include the relevant detail you're referring to as well, since `beamer` defines a `block` environment which is different from the blocks you may be referring to (in the header). Also, are you referrin got the `frame` or `block` title?